# Binding 2 dimensional Collection to some control

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

I want to bind a 2 dimensional collection - collection of collection of complex data type. So that the control looks likes (n) vertical lists(columns) of rich text boxes.

Each list will have same number of records.

One way is to pass the data to the view from viewmodel and then programmatically create these lists in the code behind of xaml. But I don't want to do that, is there something simpler?

Comment: The data should be manipulated into a form within the ViewModel which the View can bind directly to; that is the purpose of the ViewModel.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do, but how to do it? when my number of columns are not fixed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use data binding and data templates:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MainCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <RichTextBox Text="{Binding .}"/>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

So the outer `ItemsControl` binds to the collection of collections and renders in a vertical `StackPanel`. For each collection in that collection, there is an inner `ItemsControl`. Each inner `ItemsControl` displays every item in its collection as a `RichTextBox` in a horizontal `StackPanel`.

Obviously you will need to fix up binding paths as appropriate and tweak as necessary for your specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Grid.Row="1" 
         Padding="20" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="3" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid Width="300">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Prop1}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Prop2}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Prop3}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Prop4}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding Prop5, StringFormat=d}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Text="{Binding Prop6,StringFormat=c}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Text="{Binding Prop7,StringFormat=c}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```